# Dual asynchronous loops, how to guarantee correct sorted order for end result? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, loops, asynchronous

Before I start, please don't ask *why* I want to do this in javascript, just know that I need to and if it makes you feel any better, I simply want to.

So, say I've got an array with (*this number is arbitrary, real applications would be in the 300's or more, however, I selected it because it's an odd number*) 19 indexes in an array and I want to, for example, put those indexes into another array in the exact same order using **two asynchronous loops** to do it (*I'm aware this can simply be done by doing `arrayOne = arrayTwo;` I'm just using arrays for this example.*)

How could I guarantee the values being put into the second array are in the right order? 
that is to say, what is the logic or general idea to do this? (code examples are also welcome, I am also at liberty to use jquery if need be.)

<strike>Stopping or halting to wait for one loop to be done would of course be counter intuitive to using asynchronous loops because they would be working at the same time to process this task faster.</strike>

[**Here is a JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/partack/CTB22/8/) that doesn't work in its current state but shows the basic concept of what I'm talking about (*probably works if you take it out of jsfiddle and put it in a real .js file*) I'm pretty sure this code shows how to construct the loops and a check for when both loops are complete but I have no idea how to make sure they are putting the variables in the right order.

I have more than likely not explained my self very well and I intend to revise and edit this question in a few hours if there are no responses. If you require any more details, please ask me in the comments and I will try to elaborate on what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: `Stopping or halting to wait for one loop to be done would of course be counter intuitive to using asynchronous loops because they would be working at the same time to process this task faster.` Since Javascript is single threaded, the loops won't be `working at the same time`.

Comment: i must be really tired.  of course javascript is single threaded...  the second loop would be running sequentially, wouldn't it.. Gah -__- sorry, my bad.

Comment: Does loop2 know how many items were processed by loop1? And does each loop process its own items in order or is it possible that even within one asynchronous loop, the item order is not maintained?

Comment: I think it would help if you posted code that runs but returns the results in the wrong order. Your constraints seem so arbitrary that it's hard to guess if a potential solution would violate them or not.

Comment: I've fixed the few syntax errors and [your fiddle works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/CTB22/9/). Why do you think the order would not be guaranteed by your loops, they're copying the same indices to the same indices only (instead of pushing to the end in random order)?

Comment: I think I was extremely sleep deprived when I posted this because I think I really believed two asynchronous loops would help my task run faster..  Now that I'm clear headed and I see your fixed jsfiddle it has become painfully clear to me that asynchronous loops will never be web workers. Single thread is single thread, plain and simple. I think I'm gonna give the answer to @Esailija though because I think that's a viable solution to what I was originally thinking of. Someone also suggested I check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/ as well, which is probably what I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well an obvious solution is to map the items in your original array into wrappers that store the original index,
then after everything is done, sort the result array according to the stored indices and unwrap the data.

```
arrayOne = ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", "#6", "#7", "#8", "#9", "#10", "#11", "#12", "#13", "#14", "#15", "#16", "#17", "#18", "#19"];

var wrapped = arrayOne.map( function(v, i){
    return {
        data: v,
        index: i
    }
});

...

if(loopOneDone && loopTwoDone){
    //Unwrap

    var unwrapped = arrayTwo.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.index - b.index;
    }).map( function(v) {
        return v.data;
    });


    for (i=0;i<unwrapped.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= unwrapped[i] + "<br />" ;   
    }    
    console.log('All done!');

    //Code ends here
}
```

Comment: But does that make sense? Sorting an irregularly built array will take longer than it would have lasted to just copy them in order synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi well I was making this code for the case where you can't copy them in-order. It seems the OP can copy them in-order, so it's not useful for him. But could be for others.